# Angular 2 save data in services

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a set of sub components, all get a part of data from one other component. They only get data they need to display. Now I want to implement and service which requesting an server. For the request I needs an id that is saved in the main component. I do not want to give each sub component the id, so I try to save it in the service, where it is needed.

But if I call the service from an sub component the value is not set. How could I save the id global and make it reachable for the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't provide the service on every component. This way every component will get a different service instance. Instead provide it only in

```
@NgModule({

  imports  : [BrowserModule],
  providers: [SharedService],
  ...
})
export class AppModule{}
```

Comment: @micronyks thanks a lot. I'm becoming a bit sloppy recently :-/

Comment: Its okay. Happens !

Comment: Glad to hear :)